# jQuery Sortable for multiple level items

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, nested-sortable

I want a sortable list having multiple level . I tried it with [this blog](http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/) as it describes easly the things

But when i tried it with multiple level its not working :(

This is the structure i need

```
<div class='sortable'>
    <div class='item1'>aa</div>
    <div class='item1'>
        <div class='item2'>bb</div>
        <div class='item2'>cc</div>
        <div class='item2'>dd</div>
    </div>
    <div class='item1'>ee</div>
</div>
```

And the script

```
$(".sortable").sortable();
$(".item1").sortable();
```

When i assign the `sortable()` to `sortable class` and child of `item1 class` ,  all the `item1` and `item2` classes will assign the `draggable="true"` property and I cant drag the childs under `item1` .`item2` elements only need to drag inside the parent `item1`

Is there any good solution for making both the levels sortable at the same time

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "I cant drag the childs under item1 .item2 elements only need to drag inside the parent item1"? do you just want to limit dragging the `.items2` inside `.item1` ?

Answer (score 2):

Is this the behaviour that you need ?

http://jsfiddle.net/JKqrX/1/

The idea is to make the 'item1' a seperate sortable which has child elements and have handles for all 'item1' so that you can sort both the levels comfartably. You can put any image or drag icon in the place of the handler for dragging

```
//HTML
<div class='sortable'>
    <div class='item1'><span class="handle">handle   </span>aa</div>
    <div class='item1 has-child'>
        <span class="handle">handle   </span>
        <div class='item2'>bb</div>
        <div class='item2'>cc</div>
        <div class='item2'>dd</div>
    </div>
    <div class='item1'><span class="handle">handle   </span>ee</div>
</div>

//JS
$(".has-child").sortable({
    items: ".item2"
});
$(".sortable").sortable({
    handle: ".handle"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like that:

```
<div class='sortable'>
    <div class='item1'>aa</div>
    <div class='item3'>
        <div class='item2'>bb</div>
        <div class='item2'>cc</div>
        <div class='item2'>dd</div>
    </div>
    <div class='item1'>ee</div>
</div>

$(".item3").sortable({
    connectWith: ".sortable"
});
$(".sortable").sortable({
    connectWith: ".item3"
}).disableSelection();
```

Comment: Thanks radek, But item1 are also sortable indivualy and the items in child are not able to change the level. Sorting on child items and restricted inside that parent element

Comment: You are right, it were able to change the level but as much as you wanted(only parent items were able to go inside children items) right now is fixed, it is not the best code ever but you can use it as a hint. Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/JKqrX/